# Cypress testing pseudo CSS class :before

Tags: css, testing, integration-testing, cypress

Is there a way in which I can test the `content` of the pseudo CSS class for :before on my element with Cypress?

I have seen links documenting:

- [Accessing nth-child pseudo element](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/eq.html#Syntax)
- [Accessing the actual `content` pseudo class of a normal CSS class](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/issues/207)

But I have not found anything for CSS classes using the `::before` pseudo class.

Imagine the code:

```css
.myClass:before {
  content: "foo-";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="myClass">Bar</span>
</div>
```

How could one test that 'foo-' is present?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There's a way to assert on the CSS properties of pseudo-elements, although it's not as simple as just using a Cypress command.

1. Use `cy.get()` to get a reference to the element.
2. Read the `Window` object off of the element, and then invoke [`Window.getComputedStyle()`, which can read the computed CSS of pseudo selectors.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)
3. Use [`getPropertyValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue) on the returned CSS declaration to read the value of the `content` property.
4. Assert on it.

Here's an example that works on the code posted in the OP:

```js
cy.get('.myClass')
.then($els => {
  // get Window reference from element
  const win = $els[0].ownerDocument.defaultView
  // use getComputedStyle to read the pseudo selector
  const before = win.getComputedStyle($els[0], 'before')
  // read the value of the `content` CSS property
  const contentValue = before.getPropertyValue('content')
  // the returned value will have double quotes around it, but this is correct
  expect(contentValue).to.eq('"foo-"')
})
```

Comment: I had the problem that it didn't work in Firefox. The solution seems to be to use `:before` instead of `before`, which also seems to work in chrome.

Answer (score 17):

Based on [Zach's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55517628/10243834) I created a command that returns the pseudo-element property (without single quotes around).

```js
function unquote(str) {
    return str.replace(/(^")|("$)/g, '');
}

Cypress.Commands.add(
    'before',
    {
        prevSubject: 'element',
    },
    (el, property) => {
        const win = el[0].ownerDocument.defaultView;
        const before = win.getComputedStyle(el[0], 'before');
        return unquote(before.getPropertyValue(property));
    },
);
```

You will use it like this

```js
it('color is black', () => {
    cy.get('button')
       .before('color')
       .should('eq', 'rgb(0,0,0)'); // Or .then()
});
```

Comment: this seems pretty slick, but when I tried to implement it it gave me an error saying that "before" expected 2 arguments and only got one.  The commands does show 2 arguments being passed (el & property), but it seems like the "prevSubject" should allow it to select the previously selected element in the cy.get.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try asserting on the text of the parent:

```js
cy.get('.myClass').parent().should('have.text', 'foo-bar')
```

If that doesn't work, you may have to use the `textContent` property:

```js
cy.get('.myClass').parent(). should($el => expect ($el).to.contain('foo-bar')
)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, both of these end up timing out on `expected \n Bar\n to include foo-Bar`

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution to get, convert and compare a hexadecimal's `background-color` with a rgb returned.

```js
const RGBToHex = (rgbColor) => {
  // it parse rgb(255, 13, 200) to #fa92D4
  const [red, green, blue] = rgbColor.replace(/[a-z]|\(|\)|\s/g, '').split(',');
  let r = parseInt(red, 10).toString(16);
  let g = parseInt(green, 10).toString(16);
  let b = parseInt(blue, 10).toString(16);

  if (r.length === 1) r = `0${r}`;
  if (g.length === 1) g = `0${g}`;
  if (b.length === 1) b = `0${b}`;

  return `#${r}${g}${b}`;
};


cy.get('.element').then(($el) => {
  const win = $el[0].ownerDocument.defaultView;
  const before = win.getComputedStyle($el[0], 'before');
  const bgColor = before.getPropertyValue('background-color');
  expect(RGBToHex(bgColor)).to.eq('#HEXA');
});
```