# Cypress: How to get properties of pseudo progress elements like --webkit-progress-bar or --moz-progress-bar

Tags: css, cypress, pseudo-element

I have progress bar components that change color based on their value, and I'd like to evaluate the `background-color` property using Cypress. Trouble is, I can't find any way to get at the pseudo elements where the background-color is actually stored. Here is my styling (using React and styled-components):

```
const MacroBar = styled.progress`
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: ${props => (props.barSize === 'large' ? '146px' : '80px')};
  height: ${props => (props.barSize === 'large' ? '8px' : '6px')};
  border: none;
  border-radius: ${props => (props.barSize === 'large' ? '6px' : '3px')};

  ::-webkit-progress-bar {
    background-color: ${colors.primary100};
    border-radius: ${props => (props.barSize === 'large' ? '6px' : '3px')};
  }
  ::-webkit-progress-value {
    background-color: ${props =>
      props.over
        ? colors.error
        : props.color === 'teal'
        ? colors.secondary400
        : colors.hliteone400};
    border-radius: ${props => (props.barSize === 'large' ? '6px' : '3px')};
  }
  ::-moz-progress-bar {
    background-color: ${props =>
      props.over
        ? colors.error
        : props.color === 'teal'
        ? colors.secondary400
        : colors.hliteone400};
    border-radius: ${props => (props.barSize === 'large' ? '6px' : '3px')};
  }
`;
```

Based on other guides I've found, I figured maybe these items were part of the shadow DOM, but it turns out there's no shadow root on the `progress` element. Next, I tried this:

```
cy.getBySel('macroTable-fatBar')
  .then($els => {
  // get Window reference from element
  const win = $els[0].ownerDocument.defaultView
  // use getComputedStyle to read the pseudo selector
  const pseudo = win.getComputedStyle($els[0], 'webkit-progress-value')
  // read the value of the `content` CSS property
  const color = pseudo.getPropertyValue('background-color')
  console.log(color) // comes back as rgb(0, 0, 0)
})
```

When I log the value of `pseudo` above, I don't even see a property for webkit-progress-value or webkit-progress-bar. How can I access these from Cypress or Javascript? They're clearly somewhere, because the bars are changing color.

EDIT: From the dev tools:

In Firefox the pseudo element is visible:
[image]

In Chrome it is not:
[image]

For purposes of this, the Chrome one is more important since Cypress uses the Chrome browser.

EDIT 2:
HTML structure:
[image]

Right click > Copy > JS Path
document.querySelector("#root > div.sc-coaFxK.gDjsDI > div > div > div.sc-bjPkoM.gIVEZf.sc-bdVaJa.btEwTU > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.sc-jklikK.gSjtyw.sc-bdVaJa.kceFjZ > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td.sc-ePZHVD.sc-eKZiaR.icnKcQ > progress")

Comment: If you can see the element with inspect by right clicking on it - share the element properties there and may be we can give solutions.

Comment: I added images to show what I'm seeing in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I meant the part that contains the html structure. There you can usualy find the code. After you select it and then right click on the html part of that element there should be menu copy=>js path . This usualy helps me get a selector, thow it is not perfect. After that I would use cy,get(js.path).should('have.property', 'css').then(css=>{//code to use the css})

Comment: Just edited, I don't see anything in the structure for the pseudo elements, just the <progress>

Comment: Ref [Cypress testing pseudo CSS class :before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55517628/14783414), looks like you've seen this but your code does not use the full pseudo selector - should be `const pseudo = win.getComputedStyle($els[0], '-webkit-progress-value')`.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it with that change and still getting rgba(0,0,0,0) for the background-color property.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so you need to get the element, and just [validate its css](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/03/17/how-to-test-an-application-that-changes-css-variable/)

```
cy.get('[data-test="macroTable-fatBar"]')
       .should('have.css', 'background-color', 'rgb(0, 0, 0)')
```

And here are the [official docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Syntax)

Comment: This isn't what I need. The progress element isn't what I need to target, it's the pseudo element --webkit-progress-bar or --webkit-progress-value. The value should be `rgb(255,124,14)`

Comment: Try using cy.wrap(win).should('have.css', 'background-color', 'rgb(255,124,14)') isntead of cy.log. My logic is - cypress is async and it is probably not calculating it at the right time

Comment: I'm now getting an error that says `Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined` when I do that.

Comment: Try if you can get something of cy.log(win)

Comment: Instead of the cy.wrap line?

Comment: I would try cy.wrap($els[0]) at any place

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227040/discussion-between-ipenguin67-and-rosen-mihaylov).