# how do I check a pseudo element (:: after) not exist inside the span node in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

how do I check a pseudo element (:: after) not exist inside the span node ?
picture-1:
[image]"

picture-2:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is such question answered already, here is the link: [Cypress testing pseudo CSS class: before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55516990/cypress-testing-pseudo-css-class-before)