# Cypress hoverover GUI effect test

Tags: javascript, user-interface, dom, hover, cypress

I started using cypress nowadays to learn better and deeper. I am faced with a problem that I can't handle. The problem is some kind of GUI effect working with mouse hover. While hovering my mouse on the element I can't see any information change into DOM. There are just ::before and ::after words appearing. I think I have to solve that problem with some javascript tricks. unfortunately, I am new to javascript and I don't have any idea if you help me I would be very happy. Thank you! (I want to assert in some way that grey background and plus icon is shown or not)

generically look like that

[image]

after the mouse hovers this grey background and plus icon comes

[image]

you can see elements DOM here

[image]

you can see the changes after the mouse hovers element

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress testing pseudo CSS class :before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55516990/cypress-testing-pseudo-css-class-before)

Comment: hello, thank you for helping me. I think this is exactly what I looking for but their (who wrote in pseudo CSS class article) answers came to me a little confusing :) I think my javascript level is still low. Tomorrow I will try to do some examples to understand the answer. thank you again!

Comment: No problem, I'll write up an answer that breaks their solution down a little more.

Comment: I tried these solutions but cant solve my problem :(

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your screenshots, I think you have a gray overlay element covering the original incident element.

The only code I can suggest is from the limited information is

```js
cy.get('#IN-578')
  .trigger('mouseover')
  .should('not.be.visible')
```

The overlay has opacity 50%, so you can still see the incident details but from Cypress point of view the incident is covered so it will not be "visible".

If you don't have any luck with 'mouseover', try `.realHover()` from [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events).

---

After the above code, you should look for the overlay element in DOM and the `+` icon in the middle, select that icon and click it to take the action.

Comment: Hello, I tried real mouse addon and nothing changed also I tried your code too. unfortunately wasn't work :(  which information do you need to advise any other ideas? I can share?

Comment: Is the website available on the internet?

Comment: unfortunately no, it's a business site website. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events) plugin.
To install use the command:

```
npm i cypress-real-events
```

Then inside your `cypress/support/e2e.{js,ts}`, write:

```
import "cypress-real-events/support";
```

And in your code you can directly write:

```js
cy.get("selector").realHover('mouse')
//Add assertions
```

**Note:** Since the above plugin uses Chrome DevTools Protocols to simulate native events, hence this will only work with Chromium-based browsers, so no firefox.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think your answer will work. Tomorrow I will try that!

Answer (score 0):

Into cypress' test try to use the method `cy.wait("time here")` following hover command.
This is very simple but for visual test this is so useful.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick return, yes it's simple and useful but I don't know how to assert that changes on the element without giving some information to cypress.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the `:before` or `:after` of an element, we have to do a little Cypress and JavaScript magic. [This is answer is mostly from this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55517628/11625850)

```js
cy.get('.myClass')
.then($els => {
  // get Window reference from element
  const win = $els[0].ownerDocument.defaultView
  // use getComputedStyle to read the pseudo selector
  const before = win.getComputedStyle($els[0], ':before')
  // read the value of the `content` CSS property
  const contentValue = before.getPropertyValue('content')
  
  // The above lines are just how we tell Cypress to get the `:before` value. 
  // There isn't a ton to understand outside of really diving into how elements and windows work together

  expect(content).to.equal('foo');
})
```

So, using that same example, we can check for any CSS property on the element. For example, `font-size`:

```js
cy.get('.myClass')
.then($els => {
  const win = $els[0].ownerDocument.defaultView
  const before = win.getComputedStyle($els[0], ':before')
  const fontSize = before.getPropertyValue('font-size') // instead of `'font-size'`, you can substitute any CSS property
  expect(fontSize).to.equal('20');
})
```

This can also be applied to `:after`, changing out `($els[0], ':before')` with `($els[0], ':after')`.

Comment: Your code is different to Zach's, he does not use `:` in the selector.

Comment: Also, why `font-size`? The picture shows a grey color. I think it's an overlay, like you get with a modal.

Comment: `font-size` is just an arbitrary CSS property. I'll make it more clear that.

Comment: If you look at the comments on Zach's answer, adding the `:` allows for this to be used with Firefox.