# How to assert ::before in cypress

Tags: cypress, assertion

I have a ag-grid as in this link
https://www.ag-grid.com/example/

[image]

And when I am filtering bank balance to 1114[image]

This filter icon appear before bank balance

Let say I don't have any other option except `::before` which appears and disappears by adding and removing the filter value
**

```
<span class="ag-icon ag-icon-filter" unselectable="on" role="presentation">
::before
</span>
```

**

Then how would I assert on `::before` keyword only

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress testing pseudo CSS class :before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55516990/cypress-testing-pseudo-css-class-before)

Answer (score 6):

The element you seek is not a normal element, it's a pseudo-element that has been added by the CSS engine. As such it can't be accessed by normal element selectors.

The selected element using `::before` returns it's content, but if not using the pseudo-element it returns **"none"**.

With this information you can create a custom command to make it easier to test.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('hasPseudoElement', {prevSubject:true}, (subject, pseudo) => {
  return window.getComputedStyle(subject[0], pseudo).content !== 'none'
})

// when filtered
cy.get('span.ag-icon')
  .hasPseudoElement('::before')
  .should('eq', true)
  
// when not filtered
cy.get('span.ag-icon')
  .hasPseudoElement('::before')
  .should('eq', false)
  
// another example, ::after (not present)
cy.get('span.ag-icon')
  .hasPseudoElement('::after')  
  .should('eq', false)
```

This will tell you if the grid column is filtered or not.